# How can find the rows when NA data are in each column by general way in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix which has several rows where NA values are in each column. I tried to find those rows by tho following way:

```
data$missing = c(rep(1, dim(data)[1]))
b = c(rep(0, dim(data)[1]))
 for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
   b[i] = apply(data[i, 1:ncol(data)-1], 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
     if (b[i] == 0) {
     data$missing[i] = 0
     }
  }
```

After I run this function I got the following error message:

```
Error in +b[i] = apply(data[i, 3:ncol(data) - 2], 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE) : 
could not find function "+<-"
```

Could someone suggest me a flexible way to find the rows where each value is NA?

Comment: You want to find which rows have all NA values?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you GKi and Ronak Shah your answer. I found one solution:

```
d = apply(data[,3:(ncol(data)-1)],1,sum, na.rm = TRUE)
for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){if (d[i]==0) {data$missing[i] = 0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` with `all` and `is.na` to *find rows having all NA* like:

```
apply(is.na(m), 1, all)
#!apply(!is.na(m), 1, any) #Alternative
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Data:

```
m  <- matrix(c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1), ncol=2)
m
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA    1
#[3,]    1   NA
#[4,]    1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` after creating a logical matrix with `is.na`

```
rowSums(!is.na(data)) == 0
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want the row number where all columns have `NA` wrap `which` around it

```
which(rowSums(!is.na(data)) == 0)
#[1] 4 6
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, NA, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("a", "b")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can find the rows with `NA`s along all columns

```
which(rowSums(is.na(m))==ncol(m))
```

For instance:

```
m  <- matrix(c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), ncol=3,byrow = T)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   NA   NA
[2,]   NA    1    1
[3,]   NA    1   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA

> which(rowSums(is.na(m))==ncol(m))
[1] 4 5
```